# How to make an android app show notification even when it is closed

Tags: java, android, service

I want to make an app that shows a notification as soon as headphone is plugged in and remove it when it is plugged out. My app works fine when it is on or home button is pressed, but doesn't work when back is pressed or app is closed by long pressing home and swiping it away. What should I use in order to make it work?

This is my code

```
package com.example.earphone;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HeadsetPlugReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    TextView t1;

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            return;
        }
        boolean connectedHeadphones = (intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1);
      //                                                                                                              boolean connectedMicrophone = (intent.getIntExtra("microphone", 0) == 1) && connectedHeadphones;
        String headsetName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        Log.v("message", "headphone connected" + headsetName);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,i,0);

        // Toast.makeText(context, "Headphone connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {

            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            if(state==1){
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ES.class);
                context.startForegroundService(intent1);
            }
            switch (state) {
                case 0:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ES.class);
                    context.stopService( intent1);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Headphone ejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Headphone connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "I have no idea what the headset state is", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }}
```

```
package com.example.earphone;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;

public class App extends Application {
    public static final String C_ID = "noti";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createnoti();
    }
    private void createnoti(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel(
                    C_ID,"ex", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            NotificationManager nm= getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);

        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.earphone;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import static com.example.earphone.App.C_ID;

public class ES extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent ni = new Intent(this,HeadsetPlugReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,ni,0);


        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, C_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Headphones plugged in")
                .setContentText("currently plugged in")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pi).build();
        startForeground(1,notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b;
HeadsetPlugReceiver headsetPlugReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
b = findViewById(R.id.b);

      //  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ES.class);
        //startService(intent);

        headsetPlugReceiver = new HeadsetPlugReceiver();
        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG");
        registerReceiver(headsetPlugReceiver,i);
    }
}
```

Comment: registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)
Register a BroadcastReceiver to be run in the main activity thread.

Comment: You need to register your Receiver in AndroidManifest.

Comment: what is your target API?

Comment: registerReciever is already there, both in main activity and xml